# Link to a non-gatsby html page on same domain without Gatsby redirecting to 404

Tags: nginx, create-react-app, gatsby

I have a Gatsby blog. I am writing a set of tutorial posts for coding games in create-react-app. In my Gatsby post markdown, I'm trying to link to the built version of the demo react app for that post hosted on the same server, but Gatsby keeps giving me a 404 page.

I am using nginx. All the contents of the public folder resulting from `gatsby build` sit in the `var/www/html` directory of my webserver.

The create-react-app build sits inside `var/www/html/tutorials/01/`, and has its own index.html file.

In my markdown I have tried both these formats of links: `view the code [here](/tutorials/01/)` and `view the code [here](//165.227.94.249/tutorials/01/)`.

If you're viewing the post in your browser at //165.227.94.249/posts/tutorial-01 and click on the link, it'll take you to //165.227.94.249/tutorials/01/ but display a 404 page. But if you refresh the browser at the same URL, the working react app will be served.

How do I keep Gatsby from overriding this request and showing a 404 page instead of just letting the web server serve up the index.html file that exists at that url?

Answer (score 0):

The internal links in your markup are automatically converted into Gatsby Link while you build. Gatsby Link is only for internal ressources from the Gatsby build. Your create-react-app app is on the same server but outside the Gatsby build process.

From the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#reminder-use-link-only-for-internal-links):

> This component is intended only for links to pages handled by Gatsby.
>   For links to pages on other domains or pages on the same domain not
>   handled by the current Gatsby site, use the normal  element.

I think using the full URL inside the markup including https might be successful: https://165.227.94.249/tutorials/01/

PS: When I tried I got a connection timeout from your server.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to disable `gatsby-plugin-catch-links`. In case this doesn't works try to catch the onClick event, cancel the event and trigger your own redirect.

```
function processExternalSameDomainLink(event) {
  window.location.href = url

  event.stopPropagation()
  event.preventDefault()
  return false
}

<a href={newTo} onClick={processExternalSameDomainLink}>
```